# fftshift/ifftshift

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency, ifft

Please, see the the description of both `fftshift` and `ifftshift`. 
I would like to understand how to call the above two functions in relationship with `fft` and `fftn` in Matlab.

Let say that my signal has a certain frequency content; now, the frequency array can generally be stored as:

```
f = (-N/2:N/2-1)*df;

f = (1:N)*(df/2);

f = [(0:N/2-1) (-N/2:-1)];
```

What is the best way to call `fft`, coupled with `fftshift` and `ifftshift`, for the 3 study cases early mentioned?

What is the effect on the standard deviation of the signal of calling the sequence of commands or the wrong one?

Comment: This question encouraged me to ask an extensive question about the topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901519/shifting-indexes-similar-to-fftshift-in-matlab-for-own-range

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of `fft` is (in your notation) indices `(0:N-1)`.  `fftshift` simply converts that to `[(N/2:N-1) (0:(N/2-1))]`.<sup>*</sup>  `ifftshift` simply restores the original indexing.

As this is simply reordering samples, it does nothing to the standard deviation.

---

<sub>* Note that due to periodicity, sample `k` is equivalent to sample `k+N`, or `k-N`, etc.</sub>

Comment: and the input of the `fft` is expected to be swapped or un-swapped?

Comment: @fpe: I don't understand what you're asking.  The output of `fft` is what it is, `(0:N-1)`.

Comment: I would like to understand if fft in Matlab expects to have input in the standard notation `(-N/2:N/2-1)*df` or not

Comment: @fpe: The **input** to `fft` is **time**-domain data.  The **output** is **frequency**-domain data, in frequency order `(0:N-1)`.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285244 is probably the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Matlab documentation is just killing about it. But experiments show that

> > ifftshift([1 2 3 4 5])

ans =

```
 3     4     5     1     2
```

> > fftshift([1 2 3 4 5])

ans =

```
 4     5     1     2     3
```

It is just swapping around the magic DFT position [N/2]. FFT implemented in matlab use usual indexing (0:N-1). As I understand this is extra functions to prepare your input to DFT if your setup is dicrete function not in (0:N-1)...