# Shifting indexes similar to fftshift in Matlab for own range

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency, galois-field

In [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100195/fftshift-ifftshift), the result of fft is indices (0:N-1). 
**fftshift** simply converts that to [(N/2:N-1) (0:(N/2-1))].

I want to convert original range (O:N-1) to (t/N: t/N + 1), where *t* is time and assume integer and divisibel by *N*.
I am using the Galois vectors as my datatype.
**Is this possible with built-in functions in Matlab?
How can you achieve it in Matlab?**

Comment: What do you mean with `1/N` as an index?

Comment: @BasSwinckels I took a simplified example. I added more data. The point is to map the range to own range.

Comment: Your desired indices are not only shifted, but apparently also scaled. You should define how you want to achieve that. Interpolation? Also,l note that your desired index vector contains only two indices, as the step is 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, given a `data` vector, if you want to shift the range from `0:N-1` to `[a:N-1 0:a-1]` for some `a` (0<=a<=N), you can do it very easily:

```
N = 10;
a = 3;
data = rand(1,N); % Example data. Assumed range: 0:N-1
shiftedData = data([a+1:N 1:a]);
```

Comment: Can you reach ranges from (0:N-1) to (t/N: t/N + 1) with this technique?

Comment: Let's take an example: N = 5, t = 1. What do you mean by "1/5: 1/5+1"? You should define a step less than 1, otherwise that index set only contains two elements: 1/5 and 1/5+1. For example, "1/5:.3:1/5+1" gives the set of [.2 .5 .8 1.1]. Now if you want to move from 0:4 to [.2 .5 .8 1.1], that's not indexing, that's interpolation. You should use `interp1` for that

Comment: I can define "1/5:.01:1/5 + 1" so 0.4 not a problem. If I take every real value between the range, then there is no need for interpolation, I think. I am not sure.